# What is "well-typed" in TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript

In the below site, TypeScript 2.9 supports well-defined JSON.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/05/31/announcing-typescript-2-9/#json-imports

What's the meaning of a "well-typed" JSON? From my knowledge, JSON has 6 valid data types: string, number, object, array, boolean, and null. So, I think every JSON data type is well-typed or well matched to TypeScript basic types. That's why I cannot figure out the exact meaning of "well-typed".

On the contrary to this, what is "not-well-typed" json?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the example explains it:

```
// ./src/settings.json
{
    "dry": false,
    "debug": false
}

// ./src/foo.ts
import settings from "./settings.json";

settings.debug === true;  // Okay
settings.dry === 2;       // Error! Can't compare a `boolean` and `number`
```

Since any JSON property can be of any JSON type, you might think that comparing `settings.dry === 2` wouldn't cause any compilation error. It will just fail at runtime.

But it actually will issue a compile-time error, because TypeScript will infer the types from the JSON, and will thus prevent you from doing silly things such as comparing a boolean variable to a number: that doesn't make sense.

Just as if you had in your TypeScript:

```
const settings = {
    dry: false,
    debug: false
}

if (settings.dry === 2) { ... }
```

Comment: Oh I understand well-typed JSON is nothigh to do with a well-typed "INPUT" JSON file. It's just about an output data type of the JSON file in TypeScript. Thanks for your detailed description.